# Getting all data in collection in Firestore on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, collections, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently starting to use Firestore and am running in to some questions I cannot find the answer to.

I have the following collections/documents setup:

```
* client (collection)
  - client1 (document)
    [...]
  - client2 (document)
      name: placholder
      projectId: 1234
      url: string
      * apiKeys (collection)
        - platform1 (document)
          name: name
          key: key
        - platform2 (document)
          name: name
          key: key
```

What I would like to do is get the full collection with all its documents and subcollections. In the end, my goal is to save it in an object like this:

```
"client": {
    "client1": {...},
    "clinet2": {
        "name": "name",
        "projectId": 1234,
        "url": "http://localhost:5001",
        "apiKeys": {
            "platform1": {
                "name": "name",
                "apiKey": "key"
            },
            "platform2": {
                "name": "name",
                "apiKey": "key"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this even possible with Firestore? And if yes, how would I be able to do this (preferably without looping and getting everything separately)?  Any tutorial, documentation or existing code would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Renaud Tarnec for his answer. I wrote some code to get the data. It simply loops over all collections, getting all docs in it, looping over all collections in those and getting all docs in that second collection. It saves it to a global variable.

The code could be better but it's fine for now!

If you have any questions, let me know.

```
clients = db.collection('client')

global.config.client = {}

// We're gonna get all clients and their config files.   
// Very shitty way to do this, but cloudFirestore does not allow us to fetch a whole collection as an object.
// Looping the main client collection, getting all documents, looping over all collections in those also getting all documents.
// Asked on StackOverflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741109/getting-all-data-in-collection-in-firestore-on-nodejs/53741417#53741417
clients.get()
//Get all documents in Client
.then(documents => {
    documents.forEach(doc => {
        // Loop over all documents found in Client
        global.config.client[doc.id] = doc.data()

        clients.doc(doc.id).getCollections()
            //List all collections in the document
            .then(collection => {
                // Loop over all found collections
                collection.forEach(col => {
                    // Get all documents in found collection
                    console.log(doc.id, col.id)
                    clients.doc(doc.id).collection(col.id).get()
                        .then(documentsDeep =>
                            documentsDeep.forEach(docD => {
                                global.config.client[doc.id][col.id] = {
                                    [docD.id]: docD.data()
                                }
                                console.log(docD.id)
                            }))
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log(logMarkup, 'Error getting documents (global.config.client.settings)', err);
                        });
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(logMarkup, 'Error getting documents (global.config.client.settings)', err);
            });
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(logMarkup, 'Error getting documents (global.config.client.settings)', err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to do that "without looping and getting everything separately" in Node.js.

You will have to:

1. Loop over you client collection by using `get()` and `forEach()` methods, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection
2. For each client document, loop the same way over its `apiKeys` collection.

You should probably use `Promise.all()` to execute the different asynchronous `get()` operations in parallel.

---

One small advantage you may have by using Node.js compare to using the standard JavaScript library is that you can list the sub-collections of a document reference with the `getCollections()` method (which is not available for the Web/JavaScript). But since your `apiKeys` collection seems to have a known name, this does not bring any real difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's great to know I didn't miss anything, would be a pity if I wrote a solution and it turned out it wasn't needed. I'll try to write some flexible code for this and share it here as an answer!